# Visual Studio Code Arduino Extension - Serial Monitor Input No Line Ending

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

I'm using the [Arduino extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.vscode-arduino#:%7E:text=Open%20VS%20Code%20and%20press,following%20command%2C%20and%20press%20enter.&text=You%20can%20also%20install%20directly,Studio%20Code%2C%20searching%20for%20Arduino%20.) and using the "Send text to serial port" to read the user's input, using Serial.readString() in code.

However, there isn't an option to have no line ending on the input. I've seen elsewhere that it should be along the blue line on the bottom, but it's not. There is that CLRF one for VSC, but not one for the Arduino serial port.

[image: d]

The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to compare the user's input, but can't because, for example, if they enter

```
red
```

it will be

```
red
```

With a new line at the end.

Comment: It seems that [this option was removed from the status bar in version 0.3.0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-arduino/issues/952#issuecomment-604349086), but I don't understand how to change the line ending without it. Did you manage to figure it out eventually?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem...

A "better than nothing" alternative I found is using:

```
Serial.readStringUntil(' ');
```

Then, if you always send a " " space after the text, the function will ignore it and pass to the string only the text. It could be used with other characters instead, of course.
A second problem is that it also saves the new line character as a string in the following read, which you can ignore but can be annoying.

My intention was to use the new line char:

```
Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly.

Let's see if someone finds a proper solution.